# Grant special priviliges to user in RBAC

Tags: oop, security, design-patterns, architecture, roles

I am using role based access control for authorization in an enterprise software. I created three classes: `User`, `Role` and `Privilege`. User has a many to many relationship with Role and Role has a many to many relationship with Privilege. One of the customer's requirements is to add special privileges to a specific user. For example User `u` has a Role called `r` and according to that, `u` can only call `foo` service. But I want to add privilege `p` so he can call `bar` service too, even though that his role does not allow him to call `bar`.
Only solution that comes to my mind is that User has a many to many relationship with Privilege as well. But I don't think that is a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If creating a many-to-many relationship between User and Privilege is not conducive to the system you are creating, then you can create a one-off role for the special privilege. For example, if User `u` has Roles `r0` through `rn` which have Privileges `p0` through `pn`, none of which has permission to access Resource, `res1`, then you can create a special role, `rs`, that allows access to `res1` and assign that role to `u`.

Thus, the algorithm for creating a special privilege is:

1. Create privilege, `p`, that has access to the desired resource
2. Create role, `r`, and assign `p` to it
3. Assign `r` to user `u`

With this scheme, user `u` will now be able to access all of the resources in allowed by `p0` through `pn`, plus the resource accessible by `p` created in step (1).

If these special privileges will be needed for many users (i.e., many users will need special access to the same resource), then the role can be reused. For example, as needed, a new role can be created (step (2) in the algorithm above) for each desired resource, and that role can be assigned to multiple users. If reuse is not needed, a new role and privilege can be created each time a special privilege is needed. The advantage of the latter case (non-reused) is that it is simpler than the former.

Comment: Thanks, that seems a good idea. I have another requirement that I wonder if you can help me with it. Sometimes customer needs to disable a certain privilege for a user even if his role allows him to access it. How can I achieve this using current structure?

Comment: @NarimanEsmaielyFard You can add a list of disabled privileges to the user. After traversing the tree of roles and privileges, you remove the privileges that are in the disabled list for that user and are left with the privileges that are currently enabled for the user.